# Example showing that decay rate results of Fourier coefficients are sharp

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis

It is well-known that if $f$ is absolutely continuous (so it can be expressed as a Lebesgue integral of the form $\int_a^x f(y)dy$) and $2\pi$-periodic, then the Fourier coefficients will have rate of decay $o(|k|^{-1}).$

How can I find an example which gets arbitrarily close to this bound? I have tried examples like the triangle wave; all of them decay at rate $O(|k|^{-2}),$ and are not very helpful.

Comment: Absolute continuity gives, after applying integration-by-parts and Rieman-Lebesgue lemma, the decay rate $o(1/\lvert k\rvert)$, not $O(1/\lvert k\rvert)$.

Comment: True. So I need an examples getting arbitrarily close to it. Have edited my question.

Comment: You need to define what you mean by "arbitrarily close to it".  For example, demonstrating it for $O(1/\lvert k\rvert^{1+\epsilon})$ arbitrary $\epsilon>0$ isn't arbitrarily close to $o(1/\lvert k\rvert)$, because I could make it even closer with $O(\frac1{\lvert k\rvert\log\lvert k\rvert})$ etc.

Comment: @user10354138 power $1+\epsilon$ is therefore not arbitrarily close. Ideally, as I say in the title, I want to show that the bound is sharp. However, if that is too hard, partial answers are welcome.

Comment: Now posted to MO, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/456221/showing-that-decay-results-of-fourier-coefficients-are-sharp